# Save the latitude and longitude in an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, geolocation

I want to save the latitude and longitude in an object. When I use the first console.log it shows me the latitude and longitude too.

When I try to save in a variable and use console.log after the function it shows me nothing.

Whats wrong? I read that is for **async programming** but I don't get it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var userPosition = 
{
    lat: '',
    lon: ''
};

    if(navigator.geolocation)
        {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
                userPosition.lat = position.coords.latitude;
                userPosition.lon = position.coords.longitude;
                console.log(userPosition.lat); //This shows me the latitude
            });
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Geolocation not supported by your browser");
        }

console.log(userPosition.lat);      // This not works

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow this code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var userPosition = 
        {
        lat: '',
        lon: ''};
        if(navigator.geolocation)
            {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
                    userPosition.lat = position.coords.latitude;
                    userPosition.lon = position.coords.longitude;
                    console.log(userPosition.lat); //This shows me the latitude

                });
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Geolocation not supported by your browser");
            }
            setTimeout(function () {console.log('Updated::::'+userPosition.lat);},2500);
    });
```

**setTimeout is not recommend option.(Just for testing purpose.)**

Here you are not getting lat value of `console.log('Updated::::'+userPosition.lat);` 
this because of navigator.geolocation will take little time to get the data so to this reason either you need to put **setTimeout** or call function from the if part after you will get lat and lng value.

Better option is call function after getting values.

**Preferable way to use like as below:**

```
if(navigator.geolocation)
            {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
                    userPosition.lat = position.coords.latitude;
                    userPosition.lon = position.coords.longitude;
                    console.log(userPosition.lat); //This shows me the latitude
                    Displaylat_lng(userPosition.lat,userPosition.lon);

                });
            }

function Displaylat_lng(lat,lng){
            console.log('Lat ==> '+lat + ' lng ==> '+lng);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is because the function `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` is asynchronous.

This means in your case, that the main code runs at once. `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` is passed the anonymous function, and then immediately the second console.log is called.

`navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` is taking some time for the GPS to react, and then, only then is called the anonymous function with the first console.log.

You have several solutions :

```
- put all you need to do with the location inside the callback function 
- put all you need to do with the location into a separate function and call it inside the callback 
- use promises. I recommend though that you understand the callback way thoroughly, before you try out promises. While the latter gives you clearer code, the concept is more difficult to grasp. 
- setTimeout : not recommended. Disadvantage : you don't know the it takes to get the current position.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` call and its related callback happen asynchronously. `getCurrentPosition()` runs, but the function you pass into it only runs after the implementation of `getCurrentPosition()` calls it. The next instruction after `getCurrentPosition()` is `console.log(userPosition.lat);`, but `userPosition.lat` is still `''` because the asynchronous function was not yet called.

Using Promises, you can do [something like this](https://jsfiddle.net/ozzy_og_kush/8yge3bL4/) if you need to:

HTML

```
<div id="output"></div>
<div id="error"></div>
<button id="get-position">Get position</button>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#get-position').on('click', getLocation);
  function getLocation(event) {
    try {
      const positionPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            position => {
              resolve({
                lat: position.coords.latitude,
                lon: position.coords.longitude
              });
            },
            err => { reject(err); }
          );
        }
        else {
          reject("Geolocation not supported by your browser");
        }
      })
      .then(function(userPosition) {
        $('#error').empty();
        $('#output').html(`${userPosition.lat} x ${userPosition.lon}`); 
      }, errorHandler);
    } catch (err) {
      errorHandler(err);
    }
  }

  function errorHandler(err) {
    $('#output').empty();
    $('#error').html(err);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below approach

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
            var userPosition = 
            {
            lat: '',
            lon: ''};
            if(navigator.geolocation)
                {
                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
                        userPosition.lat = position.coords.latitude;
                        userPosition.lon = position.coords.longitude;
                        console.log(userPosition.lat); //This shows me the latitude 
                        foo(userPosition); // pass the resultant object to function for further processing

                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("Geolocation not supported by your browser");
                }

        })

function foo(locationObj){
  // do rest of the coding for usage of latitude and longitude
}
```